# How to watch kubernetes configuration event details using it's go client?

Tags: go, kubernetes, client

I'm writing a command line tool in Golang, and I would like to know if it is possible to get an event when a change in the current kubeconfig context has been made. In particular I'm interested to know if I can get an event when the selected namespace has been changed

I'm using the official go client for k8s. https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/client-go

Comment: On Linux you can use [inotifywait](https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) to monitor ~/.kube/config for changes.

Comment: @jordanm is there something that would work from golang code?

Comment: I've not used it, but I found these golang bindings for inotify: https://pkg.go.dev/k8s.io/utils/inotify

Comment: Sorry just realized the docs for that recommend this: https://github.com/fsnotify/fsnotify